# Meteor accounts auto login after email verification

Tags: email, meteor, authentication, verification, meteor-accounts

Not working auto login `onEmailVerificationLink`:

```
Accounts.onEmailVerificationLink(function(token, done) {
   Accounts.verifyEmail(token, function(err){
       if (!err) {
           alert( 'Email verified! Thanks!');
           done();
       }
   });
});
```

get

> Verify email link expired [403]

Answer (score 0):

in 'AccountsTemplates.configure' added

```
AccountsTemplates.configure({
   sendVerificationEmail: true,
})
```

and added this to Meteor.startup() in both server and client.

```
AccountsTemplates.configureRoute('verifyEmail')
```